# Does Shawn actually have psychic powers?

Tags: psych

In the series *Psych*, Shawn says that he is a psychic. In the episodes, he is putting stuff together and the police are wondering how he did it. Does he really have psychic powers, or does he just pay very close attention to things?

Comment: You're asking two conflicting questions here. If he has psychic powers, then he's not lying to the police department.

Comment: could it be that he just pays attention very closely

Comment: If your question is "Does Shawn have psychic powers, or does he just pay close attention", you should edit the title of the question to reflect that.

Comment: could you help me edit it

Comment: Done. I've retracted my close vote as well.

Comment: This is answered by the very basic premise of the show... just Google the word "Psych" and the answer appears in Google's summary.

Comment: what do you mean Gendolkari

Comment: @puppylover21 Shawn being a _fake_ psychic is literally the entire premise of the show.  From what I remember, him being uncovered as a fake was a plot point in practically every episode.

Answer (score 8):

It was explained in the show that he has a photographic memory. His dad taught him to observe and take mental note of pretty much everything. You can see this in an episode where his dad meets him for lunch, shawn walks in and sits down and his dad questions him about certain things in the restaurant.

So no, he does not have psychic powers. He uses his power of his memory and observation to pretend that he is psychic.

From [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0491738/plotsummary?ref_=tt_stry_pl)

> Shawn Spencer (James Roday) tells Chief of Police Karen Vick (Kirsten
>   Nelson) that he is a psychic in order to get himself out of some hot
>   water; this leads him to dragging his best friend Burton "Gus" Guster
>   to a kidnapping case, after solving that, Shawn and Gus continue to
>   solve crimes for the Santa Barbara Police Department along with Karen
>   Vick, Juliet O'Hara (Maggie Lawson), Carlton Lassiter (Timothy
>   Omundson), and Shawn's dad, Henry Spencer (Corbin Bernsen).

Comment: that is crazy because he tells them he has sidekick powers

Comment: @puppylover21 you should watch the first episode of the show. Everything is explained in that episode.